# Method to find objects seen

Tags: c++, algorithm, object, tree

I know this is not a interesting subject for you but I just practice a little c++.
Which method I can use to  find how many object can be seen from a point. ok, so here is a ex:

```
# # * # * 
# * # * #
* # P * *
# # # # # 
* # * # *
```

so, the P is the point where you should say how many point you can see, # are empty spaces and * are objects. i think i can use a kind of Lee's algorithm and where is an object stops the counter..

i made matrix

```
 f>>N>>M;
 for (i=1;i<=N;i++)
 {
    for (j=1;j<=M;j++)
    {
    f>>l;
    switch (l)
        {
        case '#': { a[i][j]=0; break;}
        case '*': { a[i][j]=-2; break;}
        case 'P': { a[i][j]=-1; break;}
        }
    }
}
```

and now, when the counter reaches a -2 stop.. please help me :o3

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain what is the problem exactly: what do  you expect to see and what you see instead, what kind of errors you get, etc. Do you use debugger?

Comment: Can you look through other objects? In which directions can you look (only horizontal, vertical, diagonal, arbitrary)?

Comment: no, that's the point, you can't see through the objects, you can look in any direction

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/15xxOzT.png

there is a pic and the bold points are the object you can see from that point

Comment: @Bogdan Array indices start at `0` (not `1` as used in your loop initialization codes), BTW!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ why do you said that?

Comment: @Bogdan Because it's true, and I think you had some (wrong) intend with your initialization with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic point here is the visibility check. A certain point `(x, y)` is visible to `(px, py)` if there are no objects on the line `(px, py) - (x, y)`. Objects can only be on integer positions. So we have to check every point that lies on this line.

```
..................
.                o
.             x 
.          x 
.       x     
.    x   
. p
```

Assume that we want to check the visibility of `o` from `p`. At first we should calculate the difference. In this case, `o` is `dx=15` units right and `dy=5` units above `p`. Objects can only be at certain positions. The possible positions are distributed on the line with an equal distance. The number of points is defined by the greatest common divisor of `dx` and `dy` (because both `dx` and `dy` need to be integers). The gcd of 5 and 15 is 5. So we have to check 5 possible positions (marked with an `x`). `stepX = dx / gcd = 15 / 5 = 3` and `stepY = dy / gcd = 5 / 5 = 1`. The last point is `o`, so we do not need to check this.

We can define a function for the visibility check that does something like the following (assuming that there is a `gcd` function):

```
bool isVisible(int** matrix /*or any other appropriate declaration */, int px, int py, int ox, int oy) 
{
    int dx = ox - px;
    int dy = oy - py;
    int div = gcd(abs(dx), abs(dy));
    int stepX = dx / div;
    int stepY = dy / div;
    for(int i = 1; i < div; ++i) 
    {
        int checkX = px + i * stepX; //these could be computed incrementally
        int checkY = py + i * stepY; 
        if (matrix[checkX][checkY] == 2) //blocked
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that this function is an illustration and might not be functional.

If you have built the matrix and you know the coordinates of `p`, then all you have to do is to iterate every position. Call the above function with the position to check whether it is visible and increment a counter if that is the case. Skip `p` in the process.

Here is another example where it is more obvious that the gcd is needed. `dx = 16`, `dy = 12`

```
..................
.                o
.                
.
.            x
.
.
.        x
.
.
.    x
.
.
.p
```

Comment: **Huh!!** Were you the author of the OP's test incidentally?

Answer (score 0):

All I can tell from what you're showing is as follows:

> i made matrix

Supposed you meant having something like

```
 f>>N>>M;

 int a[N][M]; // Note this is non standard!
```

The initialization of your for loops is wrong:

```
 for (i=1 /* <---- */ ;i<=N;i++)
```

Array indices in c++ start at `0`, your loop initializations should look like this:

```
 for (i=0 /* Note the 0 */ ;i<=N;i++)
```